# Two Webapps have the same IP address

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a webapp setup with Wordpress with a specific IP address (which is also pointed towards a custom domain).

The problem is, when I add a new webapp (also with Wordpress), it also gets allocated the same IP address as the first webapp causing it to redirect to the first webapp.

I have setup the second webapp with the same subscription plan and am using the same database for both.

Also, the first time I made a second (ever) webapp, it has its own seperate IP, but due to some issue, I deleted it and made a new webapp with the same name. Now whatever I do and no matter how many new webapps I make, they all have the allocated IP the same as the first webapp. Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to have separate IP addresses for you site?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Apps are created behind a set of load balancers that differentiate between Web Apps based on the incoming request.

if your two Web Apps are located at `example.com` and `example.org` and you have configured both in DNS to point to the same IP address, then the load balancers at the front should decide where to send the request based on what is requested.

This is going to be a problem of using the same backend database for two different wordpress sites. (unfortunately I'm not a wordpress expert, so I can't comment on what that might be - but this answer will hopefully help those who do know about wordpress, to clear up that this is not likely to be an Azure issue)

Answer (score 0):

As Michael indicated the Azure Web Apps site behind Load Balancer or ARR Front ends. However there is more to this.

When you create a site in Web App, you actually create an App Service Plan as well (this corresponds to a VM)
So when you create the second site you will get an option to either choose the same or a new app service plan.

1. If you choose the same app service plan, then both of your sites will sit on the same VM and as a result will be behind the same ARR FE.
2. If you choose to create a new app service plan, there might be a possibility that the VM will be allocated either behind the same or a different Front end. This cannot be controlled. The Fabric controller makes the allocation based on availability.

Eitherways, this shouldn't be a problem. It is okay for 2 sites to share the IP Addresses. However if you wish to have separate IP Addresses for your sites, then you can use one of the options:

1. Create the site in a different data centre
2. Create the second site under new app service plan. There is a high chance that the app service plan might be allocated under a different ARR FE.
3. Scale the site to **Standard** or higher tier and use **IP Based SSL**. This will allocate a dedicated IP for your site. There is additional cost associated with getting a dedicated IP. Refer the Azure App Service pricing for this.